# Mapping `has_many` in active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I am trying to map the `name` attribute from an array of ID's in my index view within active admin.

I have

**Sector Model**

```
has_many :portfolio_sectors
has_many :portfolios, through: :portfolio_sectors
```

**Portfolio Model**

```
has_many :portfolio_sectors
has_many :sectors, through: :portfolio_sectors
```

**Portfolio Sector**

```
belongs_to :portfolio
belongs_to :sector
```

Within active admin, at the moment, I have

```
# Index
index do
  selectable_column
  column :sector_ids
  actions
end
```

which will return

```
[2, 3]
```

I have the ID's of my sectors. How can I display the `name` attribute? Using `map` gives me

```
undefined method `map` for fixnum 2
```

How do I access `name`?

Comment: Which model is the index page for where you are trying to do this? Is it Portfolio?

Comment: This is same as this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832022/how-to-map-id-to-name-in-active-admin-index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column [accepts a block](http://activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages/index-as-table.html).

```
column "Sectors" do |portfolio|
  portfolio.sectors.map(&:name)
end
```